# Still receiving mutillidae with XAMPP errors after altering php.ini

Tags: mysql, xampp, penetration-testing

Recently downloaded Mutillidae and XAMPP, got it up and running on localhost and got a load of errors which is apparently normal with this application and curable by modifying a line in php.ini to stop showing warnings, only errors. However I still get errors which limit a lot of information storage functionality.

It says it's connected to MySQL and despite an abundance of other errors, the following would appear to be the error that causes all the others:

```
Line    113
Code    0
File    /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php
Message /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php on line 108: Error  executing query: () (0) [Exception]
Trace   #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/set-up-database.php(56):MySQLHandler->executeQuery('CREATE DATABASE...') #1 {main}
Diagnotic Information   CREATE DATABASE owasp10
```

I've only developed on Django using SQLlite in the past and have never got on with properly installing MySQL, so I think it's most likely an SQL error, even though XAMPP installed fine. I've looked through google and theres virtually no documentation about these errors in mutillidae.
If anyone knows how to cure this problem, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have pasted, it can be one of two things:

1. You haven't modified the configurations to change the default user that Mutillidae comes with. However, I don't think that's the case, since you would have seen a connection error much earlier.
2. You haven't granted create permissions to the MySQL user you are using. You have to specifically grant certain privileges to the user, depending on what the user can do. In this case, especially looking at how its mutillidae, you could just say:

   ```
   grant all privileges on *.* to 'user'@'host'
   ```

If that doesn't work, you could just email Jeremy Druin, or send a tweet his way. He is usually super helpful in helping people troubleshoot their issues.